# Где должны происходить вычисления в паттерне MVC?

Tags: php, mvc

Всем доброго времени суток!

Интересует вопрос: Где, к примеру, должны происходить вычисления пагинации страницы в паттерне MVC?

Если я всё правильно понял - в модели, но как реализовать туже пагинацию, если модель мы подключаем из контроллера - берем из неё данные и отдаём их представлению, но параметр номера страницы мы получаем именно в контроллере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь каждый решает сам как ему лучше. Никто не запрещает Вам высчитывать все данные только контроллере или только в модели, да хоть на самой вьюхе. Но правилами хорошего тона считается "Толстая модель - тонкий контроллер". То есть в модели у Вас расположена вся логика, а в контроллере только вызов необходимых методов.

Подробнее о методе "Толстая модель" можно найти в гугле. Вот здесь, допустим, отличный пример почему нужно выносить всю логику в модели: http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/tonkie-i-tolstye-modeli